# Pass variable to directive that is restricted to attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
.directive('myDate', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', '$locale',
    function ($timeout, $rootScope, $locale) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                customDate: '='
            },
            // the rest part of directive...
        };
    }
]);
```

I know how to pass a variable to directive that is restricted to *element*. But that approach doesn't work when the directive is given as *attribute*:

```
<div class="input-group date" my-date custom-date="testDate">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateFrom" />
</div>
```

Where:

```
scope.testDate= new Date('2015-01-13')
```

How can I get it work?

Comment: where you are passing `my-date` attribute ?

Comment: I have edited the question, yes, it should be `my-date`  instead of `bc-date`, thanks. It was just copy-paste mistake. 
It doesn't work, @DavinTryon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, your code should work. Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D1rFNsuTFgQRjxeQLsZF?p=preview) for the rest.  There were just a few small issues with the OP.  In the controller, the property that is bound to the directive attribute must be of the same name (`scope.date` should have been `scope.testDate`) etc.

**The controller:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.testDate = new Date('2015-01-13')
});
```

**The directive:**

```
app.directive('myDate', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', 
    function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                customDate: '='
            },
            link(scope) {
              console.log(scope.customDate);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

**The HTML:**

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div class="input-group date" my-date custom-date="testDate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateFrom" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The `date` and `testDate` was also my mistake during copying/pasting/renaming here. It still doesn't work for me. But now I know that this approach is correct thanks to your working example and I will check the reason in other parts of script.